# Why am I getting the "Duplicate variable definition" error here?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, arrays

It think Flash is telling me that my array tabData is getting duplicated, but I only set it up once in the var section of my code:

This is the line with the error:

```
for (var i in tabData) {
```

---

### TabMenu class

```
private var tabData:Array = []; // <- tabData created here

public function drawTabMenu(w, h, color, videoHDiff, ypos):void
    {           
        trace("drawTabMenu --------------");

        for (var i in Global.xml..tab) {
            tabData.push( {id:Global.xml..tab[i].@id, video:Global.xml..tab[i].vid} );
        }

        // DRAW GRAPHICS CODE HERE...

        //draw the tabs
        for (var i in tabData) { // < line throwing error

            var tab:MovieClip = new TabDefault();
            var active:MovieClip = new TabActive();
            tabArray.push(tab);
            tab.video = tabData[i].video;
            tab.addChild(active);
            i < 1 ? active.visible = true : active.visible = false;
            tab.y = topShadow.y + 5;

            // add in the textfield here
            // addChild(tf);

            // resize the tab background to textfield
            tab.x = i < 1 ? 10 : tabArray[(i-1)].x + (tabArray[(i-1)].width+3);
            tab.active = i < 1 ? tab.active = true : tab.active = false;
            topShadow.addChild(tab);

            tab.mouseChildren = false;
            tab.buttonMode = true;
            tab.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tabClick);
        }

        // set default thumbnails here
        trace("FIRST TAB DATA: "+tabData[0].video);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know flash, but is the fact that you use `i` as the loop variable in *both* loops a problem?  I think it shouldn't be - certainly wouldn't be in Java - but maybe that's it.

Also, unrelated to your problem, this line:

```
tab.active = i < 1 ? tab.active = true : tab.active = false;
```

would be easier to read like this:

```
tab.active = i < 1;
```

Again, assuming flash works like languages I know better.

Comment: BAM! That was it :) I just thought the error was talking about tabData, when it was talking about i

Comment: You can still use i for both loops, just don't use `var i` in the second one.

Answer (score 3):

`i` is the duplicate variable, not `tabData`.  Actionscript allows only function scope, not block scope as in many (most) other languages.

Promoting apparently block level scope variables to function scope is called `hoisting`.

Resources:

- [Adobe's description](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_07.html)
- [Another tutorial](http://polygeek.com/255_flex_tips-and-hints-for-variable-scope-in-actionscript)